# Get fd or handle from socket object

Tags: c++, node.js, libuv

I want to create a native (c++) module for node.js which is able to send sockets to another node process, which is completely unrelated to the current process. To do so, I tought of using the ancillary library, which has a really, really easy API for this. The problem I have to solve now is how I can get the fd or the handle of a socket object of node.js.

There's a TCPWrap class in `tcp_wrap.cc` & `tcp_wrap.h`, which has a property called `handle_`, which holds a `uv_tcp_t` object from libuv, but that property is private. Also I can't #include because it's just a module of node.js an not directly in node.js itself. I don't know if it's a good idea to copy the source files to my module just to get the that class...

Have you any ides how I could do it?

I doesn't have to run on winows, tough.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way to do it. You can find the node module here:
https://github.com/VanCoding/node-ancillary

I've just taken the headers "tcp_wrap.h","stream_wrap.h" and "handle_wrap.h" and then included "tcp_wrap.h".

I could then get the object the following way:

```
TCPWrap* wrap = static_cast<TCPWrap*>(args[0]->ToObject()->GetPointerFromInternalField(0));
StreamWrap* s = (StreamWrap*)wrap;
```

The following code then gives access to the file descriptor

```
s->GetStream()->fd
```

Comment: Wish I knew about this wrapper before I created my own! ;)

Comment: ^^ I know this feeling. Please note that the current version of node-ancillary does not rely on the ancillary library anymore. It's now done using libuv.